# Newbie trying to use external harddrive to move between devices

Tags: file, rstudio, working-directory

Changing MacDevices seems to confuse the RStudio. I want to always have the working directory be a folder on my external hard drive. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read a bit about `.Rproj` and how to use them.
R projects are a way to define your working directory and save memory depending on the project you openned. It allow to make different project without getting files together. Another advantage is that if all your data and script are within a directory linked to a Rproject, you can move it around and share it easily.

[Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) are some information on how to use them.

An other way of thinking could be modification of your `.Rprofile` so it `setwd('where/you/work')` at every R session. [Some info on how to customize your `.Rprofile`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/). Note that there is drawbacks in this options, because your code may become not reproductible when you give it to someone else.